# Scroll doesn't work inside <a> block in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, scrollbar

In Firefox, I am unable to scroll by dragging the scroll bar inside an `<a>` block:

```
<a id="monther" class="single" href="">
    <span>Month</span>
    <ul class="month" style="height:100px;width:200px;overflow:auto;">
        <li id="1310421600">Jul 2011</li>
        <li id="1307829600">Jun 2011</li>
        <li id="1305151200">May 2011</li>
        <li id="1302559200">Apr 2011</li>
        <li id="1299884400">Mar 2011</li>
        <li id="1297465200">Feb 2011</li>
        <li id="1294786800">Jan 2011</li>
        <li id="1292108400">Dec 2010</li>
        <li id="1289516400">Nov 2010</li>
    </ul>
</a>
```

Things of note:

- This works fine in other browsers I tried
- If I change the `<a>` to a `<div>` it works fine in Firefox as expected
- I can still scroll using the mousewheel, or by clicking the arrows at either end of the scrollbar (in Firefox)

The reason I am using `<a>` is because I am binding it's `blur` event to hide the `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your document structure is invalid.  `<ul>` is a [block-level element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Document_body_elements), `<a>` is an inline element; inline elements are not allowed to contain block-level elements, only other inline elements.  (Block-level elements may contain either.)  That this works in other browsers is an implementation-dependent quirk and you should not count on it continuing to work in the future.

The proper way to solve this is to make a containing `<div>` focusable by adding a `tabindex` attribute:

```
<div id="monther" class="single" tabindex="0">
    <span>Month</span>
    <ul class="month" style="height:100px;width:200px;overflow:auto;">
        <li id="1310421600">Jul 2011</li>
        <li id="1307829600">Jun 2011</li>
        <li id="1305151200">May 2011</li>
        <li id="1302559200">Apr 2011</li>
        <li id="1299884400">Mar 2011</li>
        <li id="1297465200">Feb 2011</li>
        <li id="1294786800">Jan 2011</li>
        <li id="1292108400">Dec 2010</li>
        <li id="1289516400">Nov 2010</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[See it in action here.](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/RaGgr/)  The `<ul>` hides after the containing `<div>` loses focus in IE, Chrome, and Firefox.

Comment: Nice answer Josh. This is definitely more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

According to [w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://jsbin.com/ivamax/2&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0), `UL` is not allowed in `a`, any omit of specifications can produce unwelcome results

Comment: Thanks! I will have to use the solution from @Jordan to make it work with Firefox.

Comment: @Jordan you don't answer why, but you provide a jQuery solution (not required in question)

Comment: @Sotiris he didn't ask a question, he was looking for a solution. Anyway, I'll look forward to his answer if he has one. Not bitter or anything, just curious.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to avoid using the blur event and instead close it when you click anywhere else on the page except for that widget.

This is jquery:

```
$(document).click(function(evt) {
    if($(evt.target).parents("#monther").length != 0) {
        return;
    }

    $("#monther .month").hide();
}
```

Comment: @Alex: This workaround is just that -- it is not an accessible solution (it relies on mouse interaction; you can't use the keyboard).  The [proper way to solve this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6671639/scroll-doesnt-work-inside-a-block-in-firefox/6671866#6671866) is to use `tabindex` on a containing `<div>`.

Comment: Understood, I saw @Josh3736's answer which appear to be the proper solution.